# Can't hear sound in Windows XP VM, running in Fedora VMware

Tags: windows-xp, audio, fedora, vmware-player

I use Fedora 15 and VMware 8.0. In VMware, I have a Windows XP virtual machine.

When I play sound in my VMware virtual Windows XP machine, I can't hear it. So in Fedora, I verified the PulseAudio settings in *Volume Control » Sound Setting » Applications*. I also installed the VMware client tools in the virtual machine.

If the Windows XP VM is powered off, there is nothing in *Volume Control » Sound Setting » Applications*, but if XP is powered on, the ALSA plug-in `[vmx-vcpu-0]` appears there.

So I think that all should be set up fine, but I still can't hear the sound.

Comment: Do you have the vmware client tools installed in XP?

Comment: Of course I do. I have already installed vmware tools in XP.